# For SaaS provider, is SP-to-Okta leg conforming to SAML standard?

Tags: saml, okta

We are a SaaS Service Provider with a SAML implementation. However, during the implementation with Okta, I got the impression that,

- The Okta-to-SP leg is totally SAML standard Assertion Response. Period. No questions.
- However the SP-to-Okta leg is not SAML standard AuthnRequest. It’s a proprietary HTTP Get request to the okta embed link like: 
  https://dev-xxxxx.oktapreview.com/home/xxxdevxxx_xxx/xxxx/xxx

Is this observation accurate? Is there anyway that I can make the SP-to-Okta leg SAML’s AuthnRequest? I assume no.

Answer (score 1):

Okta supports SP-initiated SSO.
You send a SAML authn request to its .../sso/saml endpoint.
The SSO service URL is available in the SAML metadata which you can downloaded from the Okta console.

Answer (score 0):

As of now the UI to get that piece of information for okta administrators is a little bit tricky:
Admin > Applications > XXX > Sign On > Settings > View Setup Instructions.

There you can find the IdP URL, issuer, and cert. The meta data profile is available for downloading as well.